# What Percent of two numbers to get to one

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I calculate the missing number using the percent and the the sum? More specifically, $7$% of what number will equal $100000$?

Comment: $7$% $=.07$ or $\frac{7}{100}$. So $7$% of a number can be given by $.07 x$ or $\frac{7}{100} x$. The "of" here means you multiply. So your equation is:

$$\frac{7}{100}x=100000$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{7}{100}x=100000\\
x=10000000/7\approx 1428571.42857$

Comment: Thanks. nine characters more.

Answer (score 0):

$.07\cdot x=100000$, now solve for $x$.